# Не получается спарсить данные курсов валют

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь сделать домашку,хочу вывести в консоль данные типа `USD/RUB --> 69.47`с сайта [moex.com](https://www.moex.com/ru/data/) не могу понять почему не парсятся данные.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


class Parser:

    raw_html = ''
    html = ''

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def get_html(self):
        self.raw_html = requests.get(self.url)
        self.html = BeautifulSoup(self.raw_html.content, 'html.parser')

    def parsing(self):
        charts = self.html.find_all('tr', class_='ng-scope')
        for item in charts:
            title = item.find('a', class_='ng-binding').get_text(strip=True)
            value = item.find('strong', class_='price ng-binding').get_text(strip=True)
            print(f'{title} --> {value}')

    def run(self):
        self.get_html()
        self.parsing()


parser = Parser('https://www.moex.com/ru/data/')
parser.run()
```

Comment: https://www.moex.com/a2193

Answer (score 5):

Парсить не получается таким способом, потому что теги появляются только в браузере при работе JavaScripta.

Можно вычленить запросы JS к серверу, и уже парсить их.
Такой запрос был найден на этой странице.
Он возвращает JSON

Собственно с ним дальше и работаем (код):

```
import json
import requests

url = ("https://iss.moex.com/iss/engines/currency/markets/selt/securities.jsonp?"
       "iss.only=securities,marketdata&"
       "securities=CETS:USD000UTSTOM,CETS:EUR_RUB__TOM,CETS:CNYRUB_TOM,CETS:GBPRUB_TOM&"
       "lang=ru&iss.meta=off&iss.json=extended&callback=angular.callbacks._gk")
data = requests.get(url)

# Обрежем лишнее (вызов функции и переводы строк)
text = data.text[22:len(data.text)-1:]
text = re.sub(r'\n', "", text)

json_string = json.loads(text)

for ss in json_string[1]['securities']:
    print(f"Курс валюты {ss['SECNAME'].split(' - ')[1]}: {ss['PREVWAPRICE']} {ss['CURRENCYID']}")
    print()
```

Получаем результат:

> Курс валюты CNY/РУБ: 11.3687 RUB
>
> Курс валюты EUR/РУБ: 89.6256 RUB
>
> Курс валюты GBP/РУБ: 98.6188 RUB
>
> Курс валюты USD/РУБ: 73.9989 RUB